# Why is Ubuntu Mate using Google DNS servers?

Tags: 16.04, dns, ubuntu-mate, resolvconf

**Update:** Looks like it's `avahi-dnsconfd` that's adding `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` to my `/etc/resolv.conf` file. I found this in /var/log/syslog:

```
Jan  4 17:00:21 freewill nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [ens33]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan  4 17:00:21 freewill avahi-dnsconfd[3579]: New DNS Server 8.8.4.4 (interface: 2.IPv4)
Jan  4 17:00:21 freewill avahi-dnsconfd[3579]: New DNS Server 8.8.8.8 (interface: 2.IPv4)
```

**How can I make Ubuntu fetch DNS servers from DHCP *only* and *not* use Avahi (mDNS) for fetching DNS servers?**

---

I am testing out Ubuntu Mate 16.04.1 LTS, and having trouble because something keeps adding Google's DNS servers to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
josh@freewill:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.100.1.1
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search my.domain.name
```

I don't want `8.8.4.4` nor `8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf` because that breaks my local network: My local DNS server (10.100.1.1) serves DNS for local NATed services which don't have public DNS records.

If I manually edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and remove the Google DNS nameservers, they get added back again by a reboot or `resolvconf -u`

NetworkManager does not have 8.8.8.8 nor 8.8.4.4 listed under **Additional DNS Servers** so that's not the cause.

The system has three ethernet interfaces, only one is connected. It's on a network with a DCHP server that provides DNS information. Contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I have run `grep -R '8\.8\.8\.8' /etc` and there's no other reference to `8.8.8.8` in any config file. Nothing under `/etc/resolvconf` refers to Google DNS servers, either!

Why is Ubuntu Mate adding Google DNS servers to `/etc/resolv.conf` and how can I make it stop? For now, I've done `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf; sudo cp /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf; sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` but I know that in the future this will bite me...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation and all comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51212/discussion-on-question-by-josh-why-is-ubuntu-mate-using-google-dns-servers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much investigation (with help from @Terrance) I discovered that Ubuntu Mate is using [`avahi-dnsconfd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/avahi-dnsconfd.8.html) and some other device on my network (possibly a Raspberry Pi) was broadcasting Google's DNS servers over mDNS / Bonjor / Avahi.

`avahi-dnsconfd` was picking this up and when [`avahi-dnsconfd.action`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/avahi-dnsconfd.action.8.html) ran, it was calling `resolvconf` to add the DNS servers is discovered over mDNS to `/etc/resolf.conf`

I disabled `avahi-dnsconfd` using:

```
sudo systemctl stop avahi-dnsconfd.service
sudo systemctl disable avahi-dnsconfd.service
```

for good measure I also edited `/etc/default/avahi-daemon` and set `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0` (because I know my network doesn't have unicast DS servers that serve the `.local` TLD)

Answer (score -1):

You don't edit the `/etc/resolve.conf` file directly, it's done when you call `resolvconf - u`.

You should edit the file:

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

instead.

Make sure that you create a backup first in case anything goes wrong:

```
sudo cp /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head.backup
```

Then edit it to add **your** DNS nameservers. This is my one, using openDNS (recommended):

```
bitofagoob@me:~$ cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head

    # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
    #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
    nameserver 208.67.222.222
    nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Then run `resolvconf - u` and the nameserver info will be copied from the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

The system needs to set it up this way for it to be valid.

Comment: This... doesn't answer my question...

Comment: I shouldn't have bothered adding something that wasn't already included in the responses.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude, I know you're trying to help and I appreciate that. However this doesn't answer my question about where Google's DNS servers are coming from...

Comment: Yes, my answer was tangential to your problem. I was just pointing out that if you were trying to edit resolve.conf directly it wouldn't help you get nearer to finding out what's wrong. Unfortunately I can't help you any further. I hope you find out what it is.